# Python 3 replace part of string with data from dict

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to turn phonenumbers into international format.  I have a list of phone number examples

```
rows = [
  (datetime.time(20, 35, 30), '0707262078',),
  (datetime.time(20, 38, 18), '+46706332602',),
  (datetime.time(20, 56, 35), '065017063'),
  (datetime.time(21, 45, 1), '+46730522807',),
  (datetime.time(22, 13, 47), '0046733165812')
]
```

I need to replace all numbers starting with ex 07 with +467, all 06 with +466 and 00 with +. For above example I need the number to turn out 0707262078 to +46707262078, 065017063 to +4665017063 and 0046733165812 to +46733165812.
Dont know if its possible to do this in regex only or if I need to do it with other code.

Been trying with re.sub combined with lamda, my thought is to make a dictionary with the matching replaces like this:

```
repl_dict = {
  '01': '+461',
  '02': '+462',
  '03': '+463',
  '04': '+464',
  '05': '+465',
  '06': '+466',
  '07': '+467',
  '08': '+468',
  '09': '+469',
  '00': '+'
}
```

My try so far:

```
import re
rows = [
  (datetime.time(20, 35, 30), '0707262078',),
  (datetime.time(20, 38, 18), '+46706332602Ring via Mitel ',),
  (datetime.time(20, 56, 35), '065017063'),
  (datetime.time(21, 45, 1), '+46730522807Ring via Mitel ',),
  (datetime.time(22, 13, 47), '0046733165812')
]

repl_dict = {
  '01': '+461',
  '02': '+462',
  '03': '+463',
  '04': '+464',
  '05': '+465',
  '06': '+466',
  '07': '+467',
  '08': '+468',
  '09': '+469',
  '00': '+'
}

for row in rows:
    regex = re.compile(r'^\d{1}[0-9](\d*)'), re.S
    DialedNumber = regex.sub(lambda match: repl_dict.get(match.group(0), row[1]), row[1], row[1])
```

Comment: Can I note that you for loop is not indented properly. Fix that first(it may just be a copying and pasting error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex, ending in `\d*`, will match the entire number, and hence no entry is found in the dict. Also, there seems to be an unmatched parens and one too many `row[1]` in the call to `sub`.

You can simplify your regex to `^00?` and your replacements dict to `{'00': '+', '0': '+46'}`. This will check whether the number starts with either one or two `0`, making the replacement dict much simpler and less repetetive.

```
rows = [(datetime.time(20, 35, 30), '0707262078',), (datetime.time(20, 38, 18), '+46706332602Ring via Mitel ',), (datetime.time(20, 56, 35), '065017063'), (datetime.time(21, 45, 1), '+46730522807Ring via Mitel ',), (datetime.time(22, 13, 47), '0046733165812')]
repl_dict = {'00': '+', '0': '+46'}
regex = re.compile(r'^00?')
for date, number in rows:
    print(regex.sub(lambda match: repl_dict.get(match.group(0)), number))
```

Output:

```
+46707262078
+46706332602Ring via Mitel 
+4665017063
+46730522807Ring via Mitel 
+46733165812
```

If you only want the numeric part, you can pre- or postprocess the numbers with a second regex like `[0-9+]*`.

Comment: `[(tm, re.sub('^(00|0)', lambda m: {'00': '+', '0': '+46'}[m.group(0)], ph)) for (tm, ph) in rows]` (Admittedly making it a one-liner does make it less nice, but you shortened both the pattern and the replacement dictionary so much that I wanted to show it.)

Answer (score 1):

This is the naive approach based on `repl_dict` as given in your question.

```
def repl(match): 
    return repl_dict[match.group(0)]

pat = '^(' + '|'.join(repl_dict) + ')'
new_rows = [(tm, re.sub(pat, repl, ph)) for (tm, ph) in rows]
```

tobias_k's answer gives a better approach by improving your `repl_dict` and pattern.

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: `^[0-9]{2}`

Details:

- `^` Asserts position at start of a line
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `{n}` Matches exactly `n` times

**Python code**:

By **@tobias_k** you can use `repl_dict.get(m.group(), m.group())` instead of `repl_dict.get(m.group()) or m.group()`.

```
regex = re.compile(r'^[0-9]{2}')

for i in range(len(rows)):
    rows[i] = (rows[i][0], regex.sub(lambda m: repl_dict.get(m.group()) or m.group(), rows[i][1]))
```

Output:

```
[(datetime.time(20, 35, 30), '+46707262078'), (datetime.time(20, 38, 18), '+46706332602Ring via Mitel '), (datetime.time(20, 56, 35), '+4665017063'), (datetime.time(21, 45, 1), '+46730522807Ring via Mitel '), (datetime.time(22, 13, 47), '+46733165812')]
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/IzU2nF)

Comment: This might fail if, for whatever reason, there are number starting with a digit other than 0. For example, if the number is "12345", then `get` returns `None` and you end up with "345"

Comment: @tobias_k Fixed it!

Comment: You could also use `repl_dict.get(m.group(), m.group())`, i.e. using the matched group itself as a default.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a regex:

```
for row in rows:
  for repl in repl_dict:
    if row[1].startswith(repl):
      print repl_dict[repl]+row[1][len(repl):]
      break
```